# Recommendations for CLI-based Anki-alternatives?

Tags: open-source, command-line, flashcard, anki

I need free software, that I can use from my terminal, for learning vocabulary in French and for memorizing famous quotations in English. The closest that I've found is [VocabCLI](https://github.com/HighnessAtharva/VocabCLI), but it is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to be able to create my own vocabulary list in any languages. Something akin to https://www.clozemaster.com but no proprietary. Any recommendations for CLI-based Anki-alternatives?